# How to fetch an Artisan Command output(file) into a variable?

Tags: laravel-5.4, laravel-artisan

I have a method(export) which calls an Artisan command, which exports the database and stores a .sql file into the system.

```
public function export() {
    $export = Artisan::call('backup:mysql-dump');
}
```

so what I need to do is, I need to grab the .sql file (or its location and name) which was created by the Artisan command and pass it to another method as a variable. The idea is to grab that file and use it as an attachment in an email, without having to do it manually.

Comment: why not call `exec()` to dump the DB to a file and then use `file_get_content()` to load the file into a variable.

Comment: I dont know how the 'exec()' works, can you provide me with some reference or document on it? And I'll get back if I still have problem..

Comment: exec() is just a way to do bash commands in php, so if you want to export your sql db to a file you can do `exec('mysqldump -u [uname] -p[pass] db_name > db_backup.sql')`, then to load the content of this file to a variable use file_get_content although I can't see a good reason to do that.